Can spyder show the call stack while debugging?
While debugging code, it is useful to see the complete call stack.
Moreover, it is useful to be able to navigate it by clicking on the various lines in a displayed list of the call stack.
Many IDEs in many languages have this option.
Can Spyder do this?
Notes:

This question seems to ask something similar, but I am not interested in particular in showing in the Variable explorer (I wouldn't know why this requisite). I am not interested either in recursive functions in particular.
This comment by Carlos Cordoba (an authority on Spyder) mentions that the call stack is not available in the variable explorer.
I can navigate the call stack with ipdb shortcuts. But I can't see the call stack as a list (very useful, with no workaround), neither navigate it by clicking (worked around with shortcuts).

